# JHipster - *jhiHasAnyAuthority directive - Display one thing when user and another thing when admin

Tags: angular, jhipster

**Goal**

To display different layouts according to the kind of user.

**Try**

I used the jhi directive:

```
<span *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_USER'"> User </span>
<span *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'"> Admin </span>
```

**Issue**

It works when I'm loggin with the user because its role is only ROLE_USER.

However, when I'm loggin with the admin, since it the admin has two roles ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN, the elements that I would like to be displayed only in the user HMI are also presents in the admin HMI.

How can I bypass this issue, please?

Thanks,

Manuela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ngSwitch` and `ngSwitchCase` directives like in `navbar.component.html` using a condition defined in your component see https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Alternatively, you can have a look at this pull request that implements `jhiHasNotAuthority` directive https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/8371 it has not been merged into JHipster but it can help.

Also, you could find a more recent question with more details here: [JHipster *jhiHasAnyAuthority directive check for "no authority"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678369/jhipster-jhihasanyauthority-directive-check-for-no-authority)

Comment: ngSwitch is perfect for what I want to do! Thanks!